# Arrayfun syntax and usage with class method

Tags: matlab

Here's a line of code that's giving me trouble.

```
arrayfun(@(x)container.nodelist(x).config(@a_func_handle,0),2:6);
```

Container is a class with one of its properties being an object array of nodes, and that array is called nodelist.

Each node has a function called config that is used to initialize it. Config expects one input, one of which is a handle to a function. The function handle I'm passing needs a constant passed along with it, which is represented by the 0.

In this case, I want to configure the nodes at positions 2 through 6 in nodelist with a specific function, so I thought to use arrayfun instead of a for loop.

Unfortunately, Matlab barfs with "too many inputs" for function config. What am I writing wrong? Is this example clear?

Comment: Just going by arrayfun's doc, it looks like the second argument to arrayfun is supposed to be the structure/vector on which you want to apply the function @config, not the indices. Granted, this doesn't explain the "too many inputs" error that you get. But maybe try passing nodelist(2:6) as the second argument instead of just 2:6?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't notice that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. What I ended up doing was using nested anonymous functions, like so:

```
arrayfun(@(y)y.config(@(x)(configSlave(x,0))),exp.pico_list(2:6));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, `config` is a method of the objects contained within your `nodelist` array. In which case, in the usual MATLAB manner, the object on which you're invoking the method gets passed as the first argument. For example, you might need to write the `config` method like this:

```
function config(obj, fcnHandle, value)
    obj.FunctionHandle = fcnHandle;
    obj.Value = value;
end
```

Comment: Ah, I've cleared up my example. What I meant to write was that the function handle itself needs to have a variable passed to it, aka http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brfpxhw-1.html